# Incorrect! (wrong value and/or wrong return type)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, return-type

```
def token(t):
    running_cost = []
    total_cost = 0
    for y in t:
        running_cost.append(y)

    for k in range(len(running_cost)):
        total_cost += float(running_cost[k])

    total_cost = '{:,.2f}' .format(total_cost)
    return total_cost
```

When I run my code through the tester, this is what I get:

> Expected: 1.17
>
> Actual:   1.17
>
> Incorrect! (wrong value and/or wrong return type)

I suppose the code does not want a string return type but the reason I have to string it is because the code requires that I return all my values with a floating point number to 2 decimal places whether it is a 0 or not.

Comment: Which tester did you use? From what I can tell, you're doing the right thing... The tester shouldn't be checking for equality of floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

You can round() your return - float to 2 digits, no need to make it a string.

```
def token(t):
    running_cost = []
    total_cost = 0
    for y in t:
        running_cost.append(y)

    for k in range(len(running_cost)):
        total_cost += float(running_cost[k])

    total_cost = '{:,.2f}' .format(total_cost)
    return total_cost

def tok2(t):
    """Creates float values from all elements of t, sums them, then rounds to 2 digits."""
    return round(sum(map(float,t)),2)

test = ['2.1093','4.0']


print(token(test), type(token(test)))
print(tok2(test), type(tok2(test)))
```

returns:

```
6.11 <class 'str'>   # you return a formatted string
6.11 <class 'float'> # I return a rounded float
```

Reference:

- [rounds a float to n digit: `round(float,n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)
- [applies a function to a sequence: `map(func,seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) - I am applying the `float()` conversion to each element of `t`
- [sums all values of iterable: `sum(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

---

Edit: you could fix yours by doing `return float(total_cost)` as well if you are prohibited to use `round()`

Comment: I still think there's a flaw in the logic of the tester program since it relies on testing the equality of floating point values, which in itself is just a poor design. But this probably solves the immediate issue :)

Comment: @roganjosh agreed, but thats how all those hackathon-challenges work :/

Comment: My previous code obviously returned a 0/10 on the tester but your version got 7/10 as there are still 3 strings that are returned which generates a Type Error. However, I just assigned `tot_cost = round(sum(map(float, t)), 2) `and on the next line, `return float(tot_cost)`. either way your code simplifies mine by a million and I really need to learn how to code like that. Its simply a matter of being new to coding and not being familiar with the python vocab/syntax. With time and practice I think I'll be okay in a few months. Thank you so much!